# Upload zip file, extract files and import to database in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, zip

I have aproblem with the Laravel framework.

I am going to upload a zip file to the server (built in Laravel) and extract zip and import to the database.

This zip file has only one CSV file.

Is there a package to solve this problem?
If this package doesn't exist, how should I implement this feature?

Comment: There are lots of packages for that, did you try some already? Didn't you like the ones you tried? Can you show us some code of things you have tried?

Comment: Welcome @Xiaoxuan Can you clarify the problem in your post?  I'm not sure I understand.  Once you clarify the problem, can you improve the title on the question? Perhaps make it more in the form of  a question.

Comment: This question is off-topic for Stackoverflow. Asking for a package/off-site resource is grounds for closure, and the amount of code required to help with this is also grounds for closure (too broad). Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking before posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see three steps, needed to solve you problem:

1. **Upload ZIP file with Laravel**, please [see here for a specific tutorial](https://tutsforweb.com/testing-file-uploads-with-laravel/)
2. **Extract file from ZIP archive with Laravel**
   You can use [this tutorial](https://appdividend.com/2018/04/21/how-to-create-and-extract-zip-file-in-laravel/) to get started with extracting the ZIP archive.

Next, two possibilites:
Either you want to store the CSV contents into separate fields/tables, or you want to save it as a BLOB.

3. a) I suspect you want to store the content into individual fields, then please follow this up-to-date guide on [Makitweb](https://makitweb.com/import-csv-data-to-mysql-database-with-laravel/)

*In general...something which helped me, when getting started with laravel was:
Most important is to break down your problem into little steps.
This will help you to structure the problem.
Next, search the net for solutions on the identified steps.
Then, put all the steps together into a solution.*